# My.User.IsInRole() is not working after migrating to 4.6.2 framework in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.6.2, isinrole

Currently i'm working in one migration request, where we need to change the framework from 3.5 to 4.6.2. Here the problem is after changing the framework below method is not showing result as expected.
`My.User.IsInRole()` is returning `null`.

Could anyone please suggest equivalent code for the above or please suggest steps to resolve the issue in my Visual Studio.
Earlier I faced problem with `My.User.Name` and changed the code to `Environment.Username` but for this I am unable to find some alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

`My.User.IsInRole()` should not return `null`/`Nothing`. The return value is a `Boolean`.

As an alternative you can use `System.Security.Principal` Namespace like in the following example:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

Class PrincipalCheck
    Shared Function UserInRole(role As String) As Boolean
        Dim currPrincipal As New WindowsPrincipal(New WindowsIdentity(Environment.UserName))
        Return currPrincipal.IsInRole(role)
    End Function
End Class

Public Sub StartCheck()
   MsgBox(PrincipalCheck.UserInRole("MyDomain\MyGroup"))
End Sub
```

But this should return the same result:

```
MsgBox(My.User.IsInRole("MyDomain\MyGroup"))
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why My.User.Name is not working in 4.6.2?

Comment: No, not really. `is not working` is not a meaningful error description. If you want to get a better answer you'll need to add more information to your question, like your code, the exception/error message you get...

Comment: Sure will provide the remaining details as well